# Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/main/binary-arm64/Packages 404 Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]

Tags: apt, updates

Kind of getting to a good stage of using Linux. I am having a problem with updating my Ubuntu 20.04. Every time I run `sudo apt update` I get "file  failed to fetch" error messages. I have tried modifying the `source.list` file but no luck. Would appreciate some help.

Example

```
Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]

Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
```

Comment: I just want to clarify that the file should be `sources.list`, not `source.list`. For the rest see Thomas' answer below.

Comment: Hi. I saved it as sources.list. I entered that part wrongly. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `arm64` packages **ONLY** exist on the `ports.ubuntu.com` repositories.  Your errors are because you are using the standard archives - which only carry `i386` and `amd64` architechtures - and will be breaking.

Based on your comment indicating your system architecture is `x86_64`, you need **`amd64`** packages, and NOT `arm64` packages.  Why your system is searching for ARM64 packages is beyond me, so we're going to fix that.  So let's fix that problem first, because you shouldn't need `arm64` packages on a standard install.

1. Remove `arm64` from foreign architectures that `dpkg`/`apt` looks for.

   ```
   sudo dpkg --remove-architecture arm64
   ```
2. Reset your sources list back to previous.

   Use something like this:

   ```
   deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted universe multiverse
   #deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted universe multiverse
   deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
   #deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
   deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
   #deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
   deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
   #deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
   deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
   #deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
   ```

   (Note I commented out the `deb-src` lines, unless you're doing things like `apt source` calls or such you probably don't need them).
3. Run `sudo apt update` again.  You should see no more errors.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your kind response. I did that and this is what got
: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates Release' does not have a Release file.

Comment: I forgot to include updating `/ubuntu` to `/ubuntu-ports` - try updating that part as well and it should work.

Comment: Hey Thomas. Do forgive me. Should I put it like this, deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ focal-updates main restricted

Comment: Updated it and this is what I got.
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]
.

Comment: @KennethShibaba See updated post, I added an example of what your sources.list should look like.

Comment: Thank you very much for this help. I copied the exact example you showed and updated it in my sources  list file. Unfortunately I am still getting the same error messages. I must say I did not comment any line out. I have backup sources list files in the etc/apt should I remove them?

Comment: @KennethShibaba You have some weirdness in your system i believe.  Your system is looking for amd64, i386, and arm64.  WHat is the **actual** architecture on your system?  `uname -i` for this info.  There should not be any cases where you're mixing standard AMD64/i386 repos and ARM repos.

Comment: Ithank you once again.  totally agree. Its really weird. So after executing uname -i I got x86_64. I have a dual boot system as well

Comment: Dual boot doesn't matter in this case.  I've updated my answer completely now.

Comment: Whaow! IT WORKED!! Oh my goodness. I am more than grateful. This has been a very educative experience for me. No errors. 350 packages can be upgraded. Guess I'd do that. Thank you Thomas.

Comment: @KennethShibaba glad to hear it!  Don't forget to hit the checkmark to accept this answer and mark the question as solved!  :)